# Reverse hide / show div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with making a `hint` button that hides then shows. Here is my code so far but it shows then hides. I can not figure out how to make it hide then show

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">HINT</button>
<div id="Hint">
<p>The hint</p>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("Hint");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, wrong comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just hide the div first :) .

```
<div id="Hint" style="display: none;">
<p>The hint</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for replying! it worked so now I got my code working :D

Comment: and I know that my question was a little more beginner then most developers but  i'm 9 so you can't blame me. I know but I just did a lot of research!

Comment: I understand :), I realized

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">HINT</button>
  <div id="Hint" style="display: none;">
    <p>The hint</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("Hint");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```